# Automatic file-versioning (like Dropbox)

Tags: backup, versioning, revision, dropbox

is there a tool that does automatic file-versioning (for local files), like dropbox? Seeing how easy it is to restore older versions using dropbox compared to svn...

[EDIT]

I know how svn and dropbox are intendend for very different purposes, and that svn provides much much more functionality, but the truth is that for my usual coding-work on my small projects I hardly need those and automatic commits & updates would really be wonderfull, considering how much time I've wasted because I screwed something up in svn.

Comment: Isn't this a question for Super User, not stackoverflow?

Comment: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Thus I flagged this question accordingly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[FileHamster](http://www.filehamster.com/) monitors a folder and automatically keeps previous version.
[AutoVer](http://beanland.net.au/autover/) does the same and is free. It would be my recommendation!

Both let you traverse previous versions and can backup everytime you hit save or every so often or a combination of both. Not sure if AutoVer copes well with MS Office tmp files though.

AutoVer also lets you run a post-backup command which I keep meaning to make use of to create diff files...

Comment: FileHampster is still available for download, but it looks like the last version was released June, 2010.

Comment: Thanks for recommending AutoVer. Didn't know it and really looks like a interesting solution.

Answer (score 5):

I would use:

- a bare git repo on a USB key (see "[developing at home and office, would GIT be easier than SVN using xcopy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777476/developing-at-home-and-office-would-git-be-easier-than-svn-using-xcopy)")
- combined with a post-commit hook (see "[How configure automatic pushing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839439/how-configure-automatic-pushing/3839496#3839496)")

You could even go as far as to do a commit (and its associated push) every time you save a file in your IDE (like a "on save" action in Eclipse), but the result would be messy (way too many commits).
An on-demand action to commit every file at a given time, or a scheduled action (every hour for instance) is more appropriate.